# Several questions regarding existence of a unique solution for nth order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand this theorem in my Differential Equations book:

Let $a_n(x), a_{n-1}(x),...,a_1(x),a_0(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous on an interval $I$ and let $a_n(x) \ne 0$ for every x in this interval.  If $x=x_0$ is any point in this interval, then a solution $y(x)$ of the initial-value problem (1) exists on the interval and is unique.

(1) is:
$a_n(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + ... + a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + a_0(x)y = g(x)$

Subject to:

$y(x_0)=y_0, y'(x_0)=y_1,...,y^{n-1}(x_0)=y_{n-1}$

What do the terms $a_n(x), a_{n-1}(x)$, etc signify?  Are these arbitrary constants?  Functions of x?

Also, does this mean there is a requirement that the highest order derivative not have a coefficient that could possibly equal zero?

I would be grateful if someone could explain this concept with an example.

Comment: You are correct on both counts. The $a_n(x)$ are functions of $x$, as the function notation suggests. And it's required that the term with the highest derivative never vanishes (i.e., you actually have an $n^{th}$-order equation).

Comment: Thanks Ducky.  So for something like $x^2y''-2xy'+2y=6$ $y(0)=3$ $y'(0)=1$ on interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, the theorem says there is no unique solution because $x^2$ is 0 at $x=0$ on that interval and because $x=0$ for the initial conditions, is that correct?

Comment: @Irongrave no, the theorem reads the other way: if the conditions are met, then there exist a solution, and it is unique. If the conditions are not met, you cannot say anything from the theorem

Comment: Not necessarily. Just because a DE fails the conditions, it is not guaranteed to have no solution (or a non-unique solution). There may be specific DE's which fail the conditions of this theorem but nevertheless have only one solution. That isn't to say the example you provided is wrong; it just requires some checking.

Comment: Thank you both.  Ducky, if you want to copy/paste your comment as an answer I'll accept it.